# What are the equations of motion for a pendulum in $n$ dimensions?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

Consider a pendulum formed of a light rod of length $l$ and a point mass $m$. At the pivot the pendulum experiences friction with coefficient $b$, and an agent can exert torque $\tau$.

In 2 dimensions the motion of this pendulum is given by (I hope):
$$\ddot{\theta} = \frac{g}{l} \sin \theta + \frac{1}{m l^2} \tau - \frac{1}{m l^2} b \dot{\theta}$$
where $\theta$ is the angle with the vertical (the positive bit of the y axis).

I would like to extend this to $n$ dimensions.

My idea was to come up with general equations for $n$ dimensions, and then check they reduce to the correct solutions in 2D and 3D.

It seems easy to convert $\theta$, $\tau$ and $b$ into vectors (to get the second two terms of the eq above), but I am having trouble working out how to project gravity into each of the dimensions of $\bf{\theta}$ (the first term).

For a given dimension of $\theta$, I think I need to find the vector which is in the hyperplane that the dimension "moves" in and is orthogonal to the rod of the pendulum. We can then take the dot project between gravity and this vector. However I'm not sure how to find this vector. I am also struggling because gravity is naturally given in cartesian coordinates, whereas the pendulum is naturally given in spherical coordinates (with fixed r).

Comment: The paper I'm following is: https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.08287. On page 7 they define it like this, but their friction parameter is in Nms/rad. I'll update the question to just $b\dot{\theta}$ for simplicity.

Comment: Ah no sorry, you are right. I got things mixed up for a bit

Comment: The problem I see with $n$ dimensions is the number of angles you will need to introduce. For example, in 3D you need two angles to describe the motion of the pendulum, each with their own equation of motion. I am not sure how this generalizes to more than 3 dimensions (i.e. if you have to add just one additional angle per dimension, or if more angles need to be introduced per dimension added)

Comment: @AaronStevens you use hyperspherical coordinates, with one radius and $n-1$ angles.

Comment: @Javier Thanks. How would you talk about torques in higher dimensions?

Comment: @AaronStevens well, that is the main problem with the question. Only in a circle do you have a nonambiguous notion of a constant vector field. In even dimensional spheres, you can't even define a nonzero vector field. OP should think about how to define the torque on a sphere.

Comment: Honestly, using a Lagrangian perspective would probably be a lot easier here, particularly if you're willing to ignore external torques & dissipative forces.

Comment: @Javier For my application it doesn't completely matter if the "torque" is actually torque, it just needs to be an action which the agent can take to influence the pendulum (the task of the agent is to balance the pendulum vertically upwards). My understanding of mechanics is pretty limited, so apologies if this doesn't make any sense, but could the agent just exert a force in the plane of one of the n-1 angles?

Answer (score 2):

Let me give you a general answer. 
Each dimension you work in, you choose a specific coordinate system that describes your system/object/motion. In this case (2 dimensions) you´ve used polar coordinates. A more rigorous algebraic way to deal with this is generalized coordinates for N dimensions, wich are about to describe transformations between any system. I think that could be the first step. Now, you gotta wonder the components of movement for each N or how the N-system behavior changes. I really don´t know how to do this for more than 4 dimensions. If you find a more specific answer, jut tell me! Hope this helps, at least a little bit =)